# Return value of member function using "this"

Tags: c++, object

In the following class definition:

```cpp
#include<iostream> 

class Test 
{ 
private: 
  int x; 
  int y; 

public: 
  Test(int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; } 
  Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; } 
  Test &setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; } 
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; } 

};
```

I don't understand why we should put an `*` in front of `this` in the `setX` or `setY` functions. I know `this` is a pointer to the current object and the `*` returns the pointed object, but since there is a `&` in the functions' return values, which means that the function returns a reference to a `Test` object. Then, shouldn't the return variable also be a reference (that is a pointer), like this:

```
Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return this; }
```

?

As an alternative, I believe

```
Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
```

would also be correct because the return value is not a pointer, but the pointed object, which of type `Test` (and not of type pointer to `Test`: `Test&`).

Why, if it's the case, are they not correct?

Comment: _Then,shouldn't the return variable also be a reference (that is a pointer)._ A pointer is not a reference

Comment: And a reference is not a pointer.

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the object, so it has type `Test *`. You cannot return it as `Test &`. If you use `return *this;`, you can return it as `Test &` or `Test`, but the second will return a new copy of the object instead of a reference to the same object.

Comment: I come from C and function can return by value or by reference, the later being a pointer, isn't it?

Comment: In C there are no references. Some people call it "call-by-reference" but technically it's call-by-pointer or call-by-address and it's the same as call-by-value. The same is true for return values. Pointers and references are not the same. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver -- In `C`, everything is passed or returned by value, including pointers.

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the object. `*this` is *the object* (obtained by dereferencing the pointer). The function returns a *reference to the object*, so you have to dereference the pointer to get what the return value needs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how can I prove that? It's kind of subtle, because pointers simulate pass by reference

Comment: There is nothing to "prove".  Everything in `C` is passed by value.  That's how the language works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two parts:

`Test& setX(int a);` is a function `setX` returning a *reference* to a `Test`. You can think of it like a pointer that's dereferenced everywhere it's used.

So, you can't return a pointer, you have to return a `Test&`, i.e. `*this`

Comment: In C, does the same concept of reference in C++ exist?. I am used to this symbol "&", being used to return addresses when applied to variables. But Test& is not an address , is it?

Comment: C has no references, but is has pointers. The `*` symbol, when applied to types means "that, but a pointer-to". When applied to variables, it means "derefence that pointer".

Comment: In C++, the `&`, when applied to types mean "that, but a reference-to", when applied to variables it means "address of that".

Answer (score 3):

> Then,shouldn't the return variable also be a reference (that is a pointer), like this:
>
> ```
> Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return this; }
> ```

That would be a compiler error. `this` is a pointer. It cannot be converted to the reference type `Test&`. However, when you dereference `this`, it can be used as the reference type `Test&`.

```
 This& temp = this;   // An error.
 This& temp = *this;  // OK
```

Reimagine your function as:

```
Test &setX(int a)
{
   x = a;
   // This& temp = this;  // Error
   This& temp = *this;    // OK
   return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The part that concerns the difference between `this` and `*this` has been addressed in other answers. Let's take a look at the difference between returning `Test` and `Test&`.

> I believe `Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }` would also be correct

Consider the chain:

```
t.setX(1).setY(2);
```

If `set_` returns a copy of `*this` (`Test setX(int);`), and not a reference (`Test& setX(int);`), chaining will not work, because `setY` will modify that copy, not `t` itself. After `;` the copy will be destroyed and the result of assignment `y = 2` will be lost.

If you don't need chaining, `set_` can simply be made `void`:

```
void setX(int a) { x = a; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can't initialise a reference with a pointer. For this reason this (which you correctly said is a pointer) is dereferenced.

Also keep in mind that pointer and reference are not the same! A pointer contains an address, can be NULL and can be reassigned. A reference is "another name for an object", can't be NULL and can't be reassigned.